# Why exactly was my meta post "What is wrong with my “levels of the hierarchy” question?" downvoted?

Tags: discussion

This question:

- Describes the rationale of asking I think well enough
- Explains why the asker (maybe wrongly) assumed that the question is on topic.
- Enumerates the possible answers the asker would accept.

What is exactly wrong with [**this meta question**](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4498) (not the original question)?

Comment: Because people thought *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*. Votes in meta are also less *meaningful* than the actual site as it doesn't cause a reputation loss. I would suggest that you chalk it up to experience and move on

Comment: @Draken Think the OP's worry is more about why people are downvoting a meta question instead of answering. Meta downvotes make no sense IMO.

Comment: [Meta votes can show agreement or disagreement. They can also show that people find the question not very useful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: related: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/165773)

Comment: for what it's worth, It's at -4 now.

Comment: Would not have posted if would have cared about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As linked by Draken, voting is different on meta. I assume you got downvotes because it appears like you're being deliberately obtuse when it comes to the reason your question was closed. The close reason is incredibly clear: it was too broad. Most people also found it unclear, as mentioned in the comments, but the question we could identify was "how do I structure a team?" which is just impossible to answer in a satisfactory manner in our Q&A format. As I mentioned on your original meta question, this is a subject people write books about. Your idea that this can have simple and short answers is rather bizarre.

Additionally you seem to be trying to rules-lawyer on meta rather than creating the thread out of genuine interest to figure out what was wrong with your question and how to improve it. It's obvious that you think the question is good here or you wouldn't have posted it, but 5 close votes within 2 hours is a fairly clear sign that your question has problems. I'm not surprised that you were downvoted if you head to meta to prove the community wrong on this.

Comment: I was genuinely interested in exactly the question I have asked, and I had no other goal than to know the thing I am asking for. I however agree that I think (and still think) that the "community reaction" I faced is mostly guided by the members who just do not want certain things to hear about and others to know, so took action to suppress the answer appearing. I have posted two questions on Meta to pay the community attention to this fact. Now done.

Comment: @eee Keep in mind that downvotes don't really suppress questions, at least not on meta. Answers can be affected by that but that's not the issue here. I think the bad reception you got was mostly due to the way you approached the questions and some of the wording you used.